# How to save two sets of data in Room database from RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I'm trying to save data in Room database from RecyclerView. The RecyclerView items contain an EditText (for weight) and a TextView (for names selected from user's Contacts). I want each name and weight to be saved in one row of my database.

My RecyclerView items are like this :

[image: 1]

I can save only the Names right now. But I don't know what to do for EditTexts... How can I save the data in each recyclerview item as a row in database?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you can save the names, then you can save rows in your Room database. So, your issue is how to get the string from EditText, right?

Comment: No it's not just about getting strings from EditText. in my DAO interface the Insert method gets a List of my model and saves it... But what about the EditTexts? let's say i have the Strings in a List. Should i use Update method for them or what? @Ferran

Comment: ok, yes, you should use Update. If you share your Dao interface I can show you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate your list that populates the recyclerview . 
First of all : In your adapter send the current position and edit text value in the Activity/Fragment where you hold the recyclerview . You can use an interface or an EventBus , after that create a list to store all the data there for the current position .

After that iterate your created list with both your name and edit text value .

Hope it helps .